# How to AutoSum the total amount of product price in JS and PHP using checkboxes?

Tags: javascript

I solve the autosum but the problem is it will not record the item name or list. What should I do?

I expected to autosum the total amount with item name or list.

JavaScript..

```
var total=0;
function autoSum(elem) {
  if (elem.checked == true) { 
    total += Number(elem.value); 
  } else {
    total -=Number(elem.value);
  }
  document.getElementById('amount').value = total.toFixed(0);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+autosum+checkbox+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor using RELEVANT RENDERED HTML, JS and CSS plus relevant frameworks.

Comment: Also why deduct the value if not checked? Just don't count it

Comment: `document.getElementById('amount').value = [...document.querySelectorAll(".someClass")].map(elem => elem.checked ? +elem.value : 0).reduce((a,b) => a+b).toFixed(0);` the toFixed(0) is only needed if there are float values in the collection of elements

Comment: Thank you sir, but how the product name value will be record to my database?

Comment: That is a completely different question  - you have nothing in your question about saving this